# What was the structure of the Russian army following reforms in 1917?

Tags: military, soviet-union, russia, russian-revolution, 1910s

Found that although it's apparent that old titles were abolished it is unclear as to whether this was merely formal while retaining a hierarchy of command or whether the army did work collectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The military ranks were abolished. This does not mean command hierarchy was abolished. Soldiers were renamed to "fighters", officers to "commanders". A general became "comandarm" or "combrig" depending on what he commanded, an army or a brigade.